# How properly set up transition opacity effect

Tags: html, css

I cannot make transition effect, when  in `@media 700` i set  `display: none`, but i want make my `.content` with full screen in `@media 700px`, how i can do that?

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;

}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

.container {
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: table;
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 15px 0 0;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 485px;
}

.sidebar {
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: -15px 0 10px rgba(51, 51, 51, .5);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .25s;
  background: #000;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 80vh;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

  .container {
    width: 500px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .content {
    height: 80vh;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .sidebar {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="header">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro maxime eligendi libero minus officiis inventore debitis, earum vero perferendis ut iste corrupti culpa. Consequuntur minus natus earum voluptas quos asperiores.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro maxime eligendi libero minus officiis inventore debitis, earum vero perferendis ut iste corrupti culpa. Consequuntur minus natus earum voluptas quos asperiores.
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please write clear description about your question? Your question is not clearly understandable.

Comment: how about now ?

Comment: Do you want to show/hide side bar with smooth fading effect?

Comment: ... yes, exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sidebar **remove opacity** and make **width** as transition property and make its width to **zero** in media 700 and also **add width as transition property to content** and make its width to **100%** in media 700

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;

}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

.container {
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: table;
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 15px 0 0;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 485px;
  transition: width .25s;
}

.sidebar {
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: -15px 0 10px rgba(51, 51, 51, .5);
  transition: width .25s;
  background: #000;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 80vh;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

  .container {
    width: 500px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .content {
    height: 80vh;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
   
  }

  .sidebar {
    width: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="header">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro maxime eligendi libero minus officiis inventore debitis, earum vero perferendis ut iste corrupti culpa. Consequuntur minus natus earum voluptas quos asperiores.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro maxime eligendi libero minus officiis inventore debitis, earum vero perferendis ut iste corrupti culpa. Consequuntur minus natus earum voluptas quos asperiores.
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```